# How to run a function in a created fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a Fragment (MapsCoverFragment) which has a FrameLayout in which I launch another Fragment (MapsFragment) with code like this:

```
// in Class begining
private Fragment mapsFragment;
// in onCreateView()
mapsFragment = new MapsFragment();
        getParentFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.mapsFrame, mapsFragment)
                .commit();
```

In MapsFragment() I have a function:

```
public void getChargePoints() {...}
```

That is, I have access to the created MapsFragment through the measured mapsFragment. 
How do I run getChargePoints() from MapsCoverFragment?

Comment: Can you create a new class for the method and access for both of fragment

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine Thanks. How can i do that?

Comment: make it static like this `public static void getChargePoints() {...}` and call directly like `MapsCoverFragment.getChargePoints()`. And you get what you want from the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Fragment mapsFragment;
```

That's all I needed to do. I declared the wrong class.